How to track sync status with CloudKit/SwiftData in SwiftUI
I've setup CloudKit to work with my SwiftData app. Now my next hurdle is that when I reinstall the app, there is about a 1-2 second delay for all of my data to reappear. When app launches it shows as no data then reappears.
Is there a way to track sync status? As to maybe display a progress view or something of that nature to make it more user friendly

Google “SyncMonitor” CoreData there is a package out there that simplifies the process
